# Qt unix domain socket server side reading

Tags: qt, sockets, unix

I am using Qt for unix domain socket and I have a question:
I want the server side read the message sent from the client side right after the connection established, below are my codes

```
if (!server->listen("mySocket2")) {

    //lisetn for new connection

    close();
    return;
}
connect(server, &QLocalServer::newConnection, this, &MainWindow::readData);
```

And in the readData function

```
QLocalSocket *clientConnection = server->nextPendingConnection();

connect(clientConnection, &QLocalSocket::disconnected,
        clientConnection, &QLocalSocket::deleteLater);
connect(clientConnection,&QLocalSocket::readyRead,
        this,&MainWindow::readyReadData);
```

In the readyReadData function

```
    QByteArray block;
    block=clientConnection->readAll();
    qDebug()<<block;
    clientConnection->disconnectFromServer();
```

but the app always crashed, can you plz advise me on that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any condition handling for when there are no pending connections. This case will cause nextPendingConnection() to return a nullptr (actually, just a zero), which may or may not cause the signal/slot connections to fail.

Comment: You are right, I indeed found the NULL pointer in debugger mode, since I am really new to Qt, any advice on how to do condition handling? Thank u in advance

Comment: Test your variable clientConnection after the call to nextPendingConnection(). If it's zero, don't do the connects. This should prevent readyReadData() from being called. For extra safety, you could test clientConnection in readyReadData() as well (in case it's used in places other than the signal/slot connection). I assume you're calling nextPendingConnection() periodically?

Comment: I followed your comments and found that the pointer clientConnection is valid(not zero) after nextPendingConnection() in the readData() function, but it becomes zero after entering  readyReadData(). I just call nextPendingConnection() once, should I call it periodically?

Comment: Or should the client connect the server side more than once to ensure the clientConnection is always valid?

Comment: No. If you're concerned that the connection may go bad, connect a different slot to your QLocalSocket::disconnected() signal. I wouldn't attempt unnecessary additional connections.

Comment: Hi, the problem was "var shadowing", the QLocalSocket *clientConnection has already been declared in the header file